# Confused about boundary points

Tags: general-topology

Please pretend that these lines are zoomed-in parts of a disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[image]
[image]
The first picture on the left is a point immediately adjacent, or tangent to, the disc. The second picture on the right is a point that is on the edge (I didn't want to use the word "boundary" due to terminology) of the disc, but this time the circle around the edge of the disc is open (hence the dotted lines) (but the disc is still closed, except for the circle).

Why is the point in the first picture not a boundary point? Won't the smallest disc you can create around that point include at least that one tangent point on the circle directly adjacent to it? Since if the point includes at least one point inside the disc and one point outside the disc, it is a boundary point. Because a point on the edge of the disc is part of the disc, and the point itself is outside the disc, this seems like a boundary point. Because I am told that the point in the second picture is a boundary point, even though the point lies on the open set of the circle, which is technically not on the circle because it's open. So the point is not on the circle, but the smallest disc we can create will include at least a point that's immediately adjacent to the point, which is the disc inside the circle, and another point immediately adjacent to the point that's not part of the disc.

Comment: A point is either in the disc or it isn't, there is no sense in which a point can be tangent to the disc (if a point is not in the disc, you can find infinitely many points which are closer to the disc). Remember, a point has no volume, so drawing it as a relatively large dot can be slightly misleading.

Comment: There is no "immediately adjacent" to a closed disk. A closed disk is a set of the form $\{ x : \lVert x-y\rVert\leqslant r\}$ for some $y$ and $r > 0$. Whenever $z$ does not belong to that disk, we have $\lVert z-y\rVert > r$, and the entire disk $\{ w : \lVert w-z\rVert < \lVert z-y\rVert - r\}$ does not intersect the first disk.